# Angry ninjas cocos2d-xna tutorial

Tags: c#, box2d, cocos2d-x, monogame

Basically I'm new to this engine and want to make a side-scrolling adventure archer game.

This engine is perfect, but I might sound stupid, but I really can't find the actual methods that utilize the xarmarin.iOS (monotouch) and xarmarin.android.

If someone could take a minute to point it out id be thankful.

Btw I have a suspicion its embedded in every-object to an extent.

Any help would be appreciated

thanks again :)

Another quick question in this engine is it possible to attach an object to another for example an arrow projectile to a plank of wood in-game, and then use the weight of the arrow to amend the weight of the plank of wood to make it topple.

Comment: Have you tried asking this on the Cocos2D-XNA forums. http://cocos2dxna.codeplex.com/discussions I've never used Cocos2D-XNA but I do use MonoGame and I can tell you that looking for "actual methods" is the wrong way to think about it. It generally works at a project level, each project shares (mostly) the same code and targets a different platform. You'll learn a lot more if you can find an example project or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can attach sprites to sprites. A CCSprite can have any node as a child, and it will render in the "z" space of that parent. So you can have an Arrow sprite and another sprite as a child of that arrow sprite, just do the following:

```
CCSprite arrow = new CCSprite("images/arrow");
CCSprite sub = new CCSprite("images/sub");
arrow.AddChild(sub,1);
```

done!

Answer (score 0):

A full set of walkthroughs for iOS and Android are available on Xamarin's website.  You can find them here:

[CocosSharp Walkthrough for iOS and Android](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/cocossharp/first_game/)